# How to change variable that has been defined in PDE?

Tags: numerical-integration, replacement

I have a PDE function that contains a variable (named ka). I want to plot the result of my PDE in 1 plot using several different ka values. However, I'm not sure about how to write down this equation. So far I can Plot this result but only by using a defined value. Is it possible to change my ka value?

If it is not possible, let say that I dont have a single ka value, how can I insert this value in the middle of the equation?

I put my code below

```
(*DATA*)
kw = 10^(-10);(*m/s*)
ka = 10^(-10);(*m/s*)
gw = 10;(*N/m^3*)
m2w = -2*10^(-4);(*coefficient of compressibility of water phase with respect to matric suction*)
m1w = -0.5*10^(-4);(*coefficient of compressibility of water phase with respect to axial stress*)
m2a = 1*10^(-4);(*coefficient of compressibility with air phase with respect to matric suction*)
m1a = -2*10^(-4);(*coefficient of compressibility of air phase with respect to axial stress*)

tmin = 0;(*minimum or time when the pressure is applied*)
tmax = 10^10;(*latest inspected time*)
zmin = 0;(*top elevation*)
zmax = 10;(*bottom elevation*)
uatm = 101;(*kPa-atmospheric air pressure*)
step = 5000;(*The higher the step, the higher the accuracy*)
uwi = 40;(*Initial water pressure*)
uai = 20;(*initial air pressure*)

temp = 293.16;(*temperature in kelvin*)
wa = 28.97*10^(-3);(*kg/mol*)
s = 0.8;
n = 0.5;
(*CALCULATION*)
r = 8.31432;(*Universal gas constant in j/(mol K*)
g = 10;(*gravity acceleration-m2/s*)
da = ka/g;
cwv = kw/(gw*m2w)
cw = ((1 - m2w/m1w)/(m2w/m1w))
ca = (m2a/m1a)/(1 - (m2a/m1a) - (1 - s)*n/(uatm*m1a))
cav = da/(wa/(r*temp)*m1a*uatm*(1 - m2a/m1a - (1 - s)*n/(uatm*m1a)))
cws = m1w/m2w;
cas = 1/(1 - (m2a/m1a) - n*(1 - s)/(uatm*m1a));
dt = tmax - tmin;
is = 300;(*ImageSize*)

(*Calculation*)
q[t]=100*(1-Exp[-0.00005*t]);


(*Coupled equation*)
eq1 = -Derivative[2, 0][uw][z, t]*cwv - Derivative[0, 1][ua][z, t]*cw + (D[q[t], t]*cws) == Derivative[0, 1][uw][z, t];
eq2 = -Derivative[2, 0][ua][z, t]*cav - Derivative[0, 1][uw][z, t]*ca + (D[q[t], t]*cas) == Derivative[0, 1][ua][z, t];

(*Boundary condition*)
ic1 = {uw[z, tmin] == uwi, Derivative[1, 0][uw][zmin, t] == 0, uw[zmax, t] == 0};
ic2 = {ua[z, tmin] == uai, ua[zmin, t] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][ua][zmax, t] == 0};

sol2 = NDSolve[Flatten[{eq1, eq2, ic1, ic2}], {uw, ua}, {z, zmin, zmax}, {t, tmin,tmax}, MaxSteps -> Infinity, MaxStepSize -> dt/step, InterpolationOrder -> All]

Column[Manipulate[Plot[uw[z, t] /. sol2, {z, zmin, zmax}, PlotRange -> Full, AxesLabel -> {z, uw[z, t]}], {t, tmin, tmax}],Manipulate[LogLinearPlot[(uw[z, t] /. sol2), {t, tmin + 0.1, tmax}, PlotRange -> Full, AxesLabel -> {t, uw[z, t]}], {z, zmin, zmax}]]
```

Regards
Martin Wijaya

Answer (score 1):

You might try solving with different values of `ka` and then making an interpolation from that. Alternatively could use `ParametricNDSolve` but this will be slow due to all the work going on. This can be done as follows. First use your setup but without defining `ka`. Then one can do:

```
sol2 = ParametricNDSolve[
  Flatten[{eq1, eq2, ic1, ic2}], {uw, ua}, {z, zmin, zmax}, {t, tmin, 
   tmax}, ka, MaxStepSize -> dt/step, InterpolationOrder -> All]
```

Now it can be manipulated, sort of. I set relevant parameters so that it will not time out and not try to reevalaute too soon.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[uw[ka][z, t] /. sol2, {z, zmin, zmax}, PlotRange -> Full, 
  AxesLabel -> {z, uw[z, t]}], {t, tmin, tmax}, {ka, 10^(-11), 
  10^(-9)}, SynchronousInitialization -> False, 
 SynchronousUpdating -> False, ContinuousAction -> False]
```

Even with these settings it is painfully slow. Possibly there are ways to tune for better performance e.g. by different settings for the `NDSolve` part.

Comment: Dear Daniel, How to use ParametricNDSolve?I currently using mathematica 8, and it seems that my mathematica can't recognize this function.

Comment: Another code that you give somehow also don't give any result (just a blank chart). So, I'm not sure why. Since there is no running sign in the mathematica, I think the process has been completed.

Comment: ParametricNDSolve is new in version 9.

Comment: You could also plot the sensitivity; that way you get an understanding how a change in `ka` influences the solution.

Comment: How to plot the sensitivity?